# How to adjust current form to the panels array bounds? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms

[screenshot][1]Probably a trivial question I heard is solved via the Anchors, but I can't really get how to apply it to the dynamic panels array (setting gridSize via inputbox before this one starts). I want to limit the whole form to the array.

That's how I do create them:

```
      _Panel = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize];
            for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
            {
                for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
                {
                    var dpanel = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                        Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                    };
                    Controls.Add(dpanel);
                    _sapperPanel[n, m] = dpanel;
                    dpanel.BackColor = clr2;
                    dpanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                    dpanel.Name = n + "," + m;
                    dpanel.Click += new EventHandler(panelClicked);
                 }
               }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u05M.png
```

Comment: All controls have 4 properties 1) Left 2) Top 3) Width 4) Height.  So you can get the form (this) properties and the panel properties.  then set the panel properties appropriately.

Comment: If you have a fixed tile size, and you have a fixed number of tiles, then you will end up getting empty space if the background is larger than tile-size x tile-number.  If the background is smaller, you'll need to have another problem.  You need to look at the background size, and from that, figure out your tile count and tile size.  Have fun during a resize